# Joining Daily Table With Start and End Date

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery I have the following out

[Daily Stock Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xClGr.png)

[Local Cost Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTh6i.png)

I am trying to join the two table together using Google BigQuery.

I am sure you can use the lead function to create a next cost effective date however I am struggling on how to do that. Any ideas in BigQuery?

Comment: Could you please show the example output required?